# How to use cypher to limit action to one relationship of several

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a neo4j database that contains a one-to-many relationship between (s) and (u). There can easily be up to ~ 100 (u) for each (s).

I would like to return all (s) nodes but linked to just one (u) nodes, and then do something with that. More specifically, I am copying a property from the (u) node to the (s) node. i.e. I don't want to return all (s)--(u) relationships, just one (u) for each (s).

I've tried:

```
MATCH (s)--(u) WITH s, u LIMIT 1 SET s.prop = u.prop
```

But this returns only one for all (s) nodes, whereas I'm trying to return one (u) for each (s) node.

EDIT: Another method, which seems to work, but be rather slow, is as follows:

```
MATCH (s)--(u)
WITH s, HEAD(COLLECT(u.existprop)) AS prop
SET s.newprop = prop
RETURN s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others trying to do the same thing, this is what I ended up doing:

```
MATCH (s)--(u)
WITH s, HEAD(COLLECT(u.existprop)) AS prop
SET s.newprop = prop
RETURN s
```

This works by first collecting the properties from the (u) nodes, then selecting the first of these properties. I am not currently aware of another way, but it would be nice if there is a way to select the first item without first having to return and collect all other items.